# Why do I have two companions in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I have completed the dark brotherhood questline and had Cicero as my follower, then I downloaded the Dawngaurd DLC and completed that questline. Through the whole storyline I had Serana follow me as well as Cicero, but then even after the quest line she still follows me, so now I have Cicero and Serana. Why, is it a glich?

Comment: It sounds like a glitch or an exploit... I wouldn't complain tbh the more the merrier! :P

Answer (score 2):

Many parts of the Dawnguard questline outright require Serana as your follower, and several of those quests are able to add her as your follower, even though you already have one.

The [list of bugs associated with Serana](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Serana#Bugs) is rather large. She's the single most complex NPC in the entire game, with an entire hidden quest (called `DLC1NPCMentalModel`)acting under the hood to control her behavior, her dialog, etc., independent of the stuff that goes on as part of the actual quests.

It is incredibly likely that you have encountered a bug whereby the hidden quest got in an odd state, and didn't properly notice that she should have left after one of the forced-follower points. In that case, you may not even be able to get rid of her as a follower without resorting to console commands (and those only work if you're on the PC).

Comment: I have another problem, before I got the dawngaurd dlc I went into a building and Cicero didn't follow. When I went back outside he was gone. He stayed gone for about a week( real time) then just randomly popped up. But ever since he disappeared , even in full deadric armor he only takes one hit to be downed, and with a dearic sword he does almost no damage... He did not use to be this weak. Is this one if skyrim's many bugs or is there a particular reason and if so how can I fix it?

Comment: No clue. Since this is a different issue, you should ask it as another question. And, of course, if you found my answer useful, hit the checkmark on the left of it to mark it as accepted.